# $\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}\times \mathbb{N}$ not isomorphic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Show that the sets $W=\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$ and $W'=\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}$, ordered lexicographically are non-isomorphic well-ordered sets.

Any hints on how to prove this?

Comment: Can you draw a picture of these two orders?

Comment: Think about what is special about $(1,0) \in W'$

Comment: Well, $W$ would be two horizontal dashed lines at heights $y=0$ and $y=1$, and the order goes $(0,0)<(0,1)<(1,0)<(1,1)$ in kind of "zig-zag", right? For $W'$ it is two vertical dashed lines at $x=0$ and $x=1$, and the order goes $(0,0)<(0,1)<....<(0,n)<(1,0)<(1,1)<...<(1,n)$, right? Now that I have drawn the pictures, intuitively it's clear the orders are different but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Is maybe $(1,0)\in W'$ different because it has infinitely many points in the set that are less than it?

Comment: Hint: One of them is isomorphic to $\Bbb N$, the other isn't.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, since you can assign $(0,0)\mapsto 0,(0,1)\mapsto 1,(1,0)\mapsto 2,(1,1)\mapsto 3...$ and maybe prove that is an isomorphism. But it remains to prove that indeed that function is an isomorphism, and that $\{0,1\}\times\mathbb{N}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, right?

Comment: If you know the well-order comparison theorem (and in particular the uniqueness of the result), that might provide a guide on how to proceed: try to find an order isomorphism between $W$ and a proper initial segment of $W'$, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD: changed ordering convention.**

Consider an element $y=(1, 0) \in W'$. It has infinite number of predecessors. In $W$ every element has only finite number of predecessors.

Now assume there is an order preserving isomorphism $f : W \mapsto W'$. Take $x \in W$ such that $f(x)=y$. Let $X= \{x' \in W | x' < x\}$ and $Y= \{y' \in W' | y' < y\}$ and $X'= \{f^{-1}(y) \in W | y \in Y\}$. Since $f$ in an isomorphism there is bijection between $Y$ and $X'$. Since $f$ preserves order, $X' \subset X$. So $|Y| = |X'| \le |X|$, a contradiction since Y is not finite.

Comment: Isn't $(0,0)$ the predecessor of $(0,1)$ in $W?

Comment: I still do not get it. Maybe you mean the point $(1,0)$ in $W'$, if I am not mistaken that is the one that doesn't have a predecessor.

Comment: I think you have it backwards - unless maybe for some reason you're using lexicographic comparison on the second elements first and then on the first elements.  But as far as I know that's not the standard lexicographic product order.

Comment: Why does the fact that $f$ is an isomorphism imply that there is a bijection between $Y$ and $X'$?

Comment: And isomorphism is bijection by definition and $X'$ is and image of $Y$ under $f^{-1}$

Comment: Of course. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this to practice MathJax, so ignore.

$$
\begin{matrix}
\bullet & \rightarrow& \bullet\\
& \swarrow\\
\bullet & \rightarrow& \bullet\\
& \swarrow\\
\bullet & \rightarrow& \bullet\\
& \swarrow\\
\bullet & \rightarrow& \bullet\\
& \swarrow\\
\bullet & \rightarrow& \bullet\\
& \swarrow\\
&\cdots\\
&\cdots
\end{matrix}
$$


$$
\begin{matrix}
\bullet & \rightarrow& \bullet & \rightarrow &\bullet & \rightarrow &\bullet
& \rightarrow &\bullet & \rightarrow &\bullet \rightarrow \cdots\\
&&&&&&&&&&\swarrow\\
&&\longleftarrow&\longleftarrow&\longleftarrow&\longleftarrow&\longleftarrow&\longleftarrow&\longleftarrow&\longleftarrow\\
&\swarrow\\
\bullet & \rightarrow& \bullet & \rightarrow &\bullet & \rightarrow &\bullet
& \rightarrow &\bullet & \rightarrow &\bullet \rightarrow \cdots\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: Nice work.  I did not ignore.